# difference between table of factor and table of character

Tags: r, r-factor

can anyone kindly explain to me what is the difference between the below:

```
 length(table(ari_kiddivax_temp$SAMPLE_ID))
```

which gives 2165

```
length(table(as.character(ari_kiddivax_temp$SAMPLE_ID)))
```

which gives 1439

I have this output from R:

```
class(ari_kiddivax_temp$SAMPLE_ID)
[1] "factor"

head(ari_kiddivax_temp$SAMPLE_ID)
[1] 91010 91010 91010 91010 91011 91011
2165 Levels: 91010 91011 91012 91013 91020 91021 91022 91030 91031 91032 91033 91040 91041 91042 91043 ... 2754
```

Could someone kindly explain why they are different? one gives me 2165, the other gives 1439. There must be some difference of adding the "as.character" in there. But I don't know why it makes a difference and how it makes a difference.

P.S. Also what is the best way of avoiding making such silly mistake?

Comment: You probably have empty levels. Try `length(table(factor(ari_kiddivax_temp$SAMPLE_ID)))`

Comment: I have this: length(table(factor(ari_kiddivax_temp$SAMPLE_ID)))
[1] 1439

Comment: So you fine then. It gives you the same result as is with `as.character`

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" level?? You mean the factor for those 2165-1439 = 726 individuals are "NA"???

Comment: No. Try `test <- factor("a", levels = letters[1:4]) ; test` You have one value and 3 empty levels. Compare `table(test) ; table(as.character(test)) ; table(factor(test))`

Comment: Hi, I still don't really understand. I have tried these two:   test <- factor(c("a","c"), levels = letters[1:4])     ,     length(test)
[1] 2

Comment: test <- factor(c("a","c"), levels = letters[6:10])  , test
[1] <NA> <NA>
Levels: f g h i j     and   length(test)
[1] 2

Comment: You haven't used `table` in your first try, it should be `test <- factor(c("a","c"), levels = letters[1:4]) ; length(table(test))`. In your second try non of the values matched the levels so its only `NA`s. Either way, it seems like you are not paying attention and I'm not going to spend my whole day in answering your comments. Please read this http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html

Comment: Hi, but I got these to be:    test <- factor(c("a","a"), levels = letters[1:4])  ,  length(table(test)) = 4  and the one below (in another comment here below)

Comment: test <- factor(c("a","a"), levels = letters[6:9])      ,   length(table(test)) =4  . They are the same length.  But I don't understand why.  > test
[1] <NA> <NA>
Levels: f g h i

Comment: So could you explain why the difference of the two numbers? what happen to the 726 difference?

Comment: I just did and gave you lots of examples.

Comment: But I am specifically wanting to know why the "length" function gives two different number in the very first post of the question above. I mean why one gives 2165, but the other gives 1439.

Comment: But I have the same "length" when I tried out your example. Or even my examples just created in these comments.

Comment: Because you are checking the length of the **table** you made, **not** the length of the actual vector. `length(table(x))` isn't the same as `length(x)`. Please check what `table` gives you and then work the logic thru.

Comment: Impressed by your stamina today @DavidArenburg.

Comment: David gave you everything you needed to understand (and maybe more) with a very good explanation and examples. Just say thanks, take all those with you and do your homework...